# How to install Chrome Browser on Ubuntu

Tags: software-installation, google-chrome

I'm on Ubuntu 22.04 LTS,I couldn't find Google Chrome in the Snap store, so how can I install it?

Answer (score 5):

You can use the [chrome website](https://www.google.com/chrome/?brand=JJTC&gclid=CjwKCAjw1ICZBhAzEiwAFfvFhMpPrxhrIDiaXgbYuMoANRBfWsJL7dOQan2L6xvBtmuuni0iNczxfRoCEtsQAvD_BwE&gclsrc=aw.ds) for that. It will list there for what OS the download is and you can use Ubuntu/GNome Software Center to have it install the file.

Or you can add a key, setup the repository, update and install:

```
wget -q -O - https://dl-ssl.google.com/linux/linux_signing_key.pub | sudo apt-key add - 
sudo sh -c 'echo "deb [arch=amd64] http://dl.google.com/linux/chrome/deb/ stable main" >> /etc/apt/sources.list.d/google.list'

sudo apt-get update
```

There are options to choose from; install one of these (versions at the moment are 107.0.5286.2-1, 106.0.5249.30-1, and 105.0.5195.102-1):

```
sudo apt install google-chrome-unstable     
sudo apt install google-chrome-beta
sudo apt install google-chrome-stable
```

Comment: Thanks it worked